# getting error when openssl is enabled

Tags: php, openssl

When I am trying to run my website with openssl enabled, I am getting Fatal error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". But when I am running the site without openssl I am getting "Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? 
HTTP-SSL support is not available in this build".

I am using xampp 1.8.0

when I checked phpinfo, the openssl library & header versions are different

Comment: The question is I am not able to run my projects; the issue is when I run the project in openssl enabled its throwing me a error saying max exe time exceeded. And when i run the project if openssl is disabled its throwing a different error saying unable to find the wrapper "https".

Comment: You are using the HTTPS wrapper in your project. As long as it is not enabled (it needs openssl, so you get the error if openssl is disbaled), it would not work. So now you enable it and you get a timeout. Check with another HTTPS link first you know that is working. Report back if you get it to work. If it does not work with even 10+ other HTTPS URLs, say which ones you've tested with and their error messages.